# tf14087 Cannot undelete [file] because not all of the deletion is being undeleted

Tags: version-control, tfs, merge

We are getting this error when we try to merge from a development branch (Dev) back to its parent branch (Main).  Main did have some changesets rolled back a few weeks ago which included the deletion of some folders which exist in Dev.  We believe this is the source of the problem.  What is the best way to resolve this.

Main should pretty much match up with Dev but currently it is missing some sub folders.  How can I get these folders / files to move from Dev to Main?  We are trying to manually resolve the changes but it is a bit of a mess.  It hard to believe that TFS makes things this hard to resolve.

Comment: I'm seeing the very same problem. Did you found a solution?

Comment: @jpbochi - I managed to resolve the issue but i dont know how the fix can easily be reused.  The problem was Files were deleted from the Main branch so when we tried to merge Dev to Main it could not re-add the files from Dev to Main.  The solution was to undelete the deleted files in Main (theres an option in VS under Settings > Source Control to show deleted files) then merge again.  It was a long process with several steps but this was the main gist of it.  If you want more info just explain the situation in a reply or new question and ill see if i can help.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mrod/archive/2006/10/10/the-logic-and-reason-behind-error-message-tf14087.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into this weird error as well. This [blog article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mrod/archive/2006/10/10/the-logic-and-reason-behind-error-message-tf14087.aspx) explains it a lot better. [And this one](http://www.paul-kearney.com/2010/09/2010-09-03-resolving-tfs-error-tf14087.html) gives you a practical solution.